# Running Test cases for Azure automatically

Tags: testing, azure-devops, testcase, test-suite

I have written more than 300 test cases in Azure. Now I have to execute them one by one.

But I want to run all of them automatically. Is there any way to run all of them automatically instead of executing them manually one by one?

If there is any way, then kindly guide me

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check the answers below? Hope the information could help resolve your concerns. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

> I have written more than 300 test cases in Azure.

For the test cases, if you mean the [test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-test-cases?view=azure-devops) created in Azure Test Plans, please note that they are the **manual** test cases to check that each deliverable meets your users' needs. Manual test cases define individual steps testers perform, including steps that are shared across test cases. So they are designed to execute manually according to the steps that are defined in each of them.

If you have defined test methods in your code and would expect to integrate the code tests with the test cases in your test plan, you can take reference to the two documents below.

[Associate automated tests with test cases - Azure Test Plans | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops)

[Run automated tests from test plans - Azure Test Plans | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops)

Hope the information could help.

Answer (score 0):

Since it was a web app, we can triger it automatically with Katalon

You can learn about how to use Katalon in this website https://academy.katalon.com/

Hope it will reduce your own pain to run your test cases. Thank you